# how can I create a Query log can be enabled for Analysis Services tabular mode instances?

Tags: ssas, logging

I know that "Query log can be enabled for Analysis Services multidimensional mode instances only. Query log cannot be enabled for tabular mode instances." But is there a way I can do query logging for tabular mode instances? Even using 3rd party tools?

Thanks :)